# How to bind to WPF View with two objects in a Many to Many Relationship?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, observablecollection

Given I have a many to many relationship in my data access layer (using CodeFirst - EF) e.g.

```
public class Report{
   public int ReportId {get;set;}
   public string ReportName {get;set;}
   public List<ReportKeyword> ReportKeywords {get;set;}
}

public class ReportKeyword{
   public int ReportId {get;set;}
   public int KeywordId {get;set;}
}

public class Keyword{
   public int KeywordId {get;set;}
   public string KeywordName {get;set;}
   public List<ReportKeyword> ReportKeywords {get;set;}
}
```

I need to create a user interface (WPF View) that displays a listview of reports and each report should display a child list view of its keywords. Therefore this can be done easily in a ViewModel but what is the best way of modelling your ViewModel for this purpose. Do I need to create a VM with the necessary properties? That is a ReportViewModel with all the similar properties I want to display off the report object, including a collection of Keywords.

```
public class ReportViewModel : ViewModelBase<ReportViewModel>
{
    private string _reportName;
    public string ReportName
    {
        get { return _reportName; }
        set
        {
            _reportName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(model => model.ReportName);
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Keyword> _keywords;
    public ObservableCollection<Keyword> Keywords
    {
        get { return _keywords; }
        set
        {
            _keywords = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(model => model.Keywords);
        }
    }

}
```

I feel its a bit tedious. How do I populate the collection to display on the grid? Should it be when a report is selected, call a method that sets the Keywords collection? Is there a better solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal opinion, you seem to almost be there already. However, I would provide the view model with a collection of `Report` objects, a single property of type `Report` to bind to the `SelectedItem` property of a collection control instead of the collection of `Keyword` objects that you have already.

With this view model, I would bind the `Reports` property to a `ListBox.ItemsSource` in the view and the `Report` property to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property, so that users can select the various report objects. Then you can simply bind the `ReportKeywords` property from the selected `Report` object to the another `ListBox` in the view:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Reports/ReportKeywords}" />
```

This should bind to the `ReportKeywords` collection of the current, or selected item in the other `ListBox`.